# Firestore query for last specific days | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some documents that contain a timestamp which was set with `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and I would like to query the documents based on last 5, 10 or 30 days.

Can this be achieved by using Firestore queries of do I have to pull all data and filter on the client?

Now I am getting the documents like this:

```
QuerySnapshot qShot = await _db
    .collection('content')
    .document(userID)
    .collection('favorites')
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .getDocuments().catchError((onError){print(onError);});
```

Edit (After adding .where('timestamp', isGreaterThan: '5DAYSOLD_TIMESTAMP'));

result is flutter: documents []

Edit

The timestamp generated by `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` looks like this  `May 12, 2020 at 2:46:46 PM UTC+3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,
Since Firestore saves the timestamp in milliseconds from the epoch, You can generate a timestamp of 5 days before in front end and query the database.

```
int x = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:5)).toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Now you can modify your query to show all the results where the timestamp is greater than x.

So your code will be updated as

```
QuerySnapshot qShot = await _db
.collection('content')
.document(userID)
.collection('favorites')
.where('timestamp',isGreaterThan:x)
.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
.getDocuments().catchError((onError){print(onError);});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have to query using the timestamp like this

```
DateTime currentDate= DateTime.now();
DateTime queryDate= currentDate.substract(Duration(days:5));
Timestamp  timestamp= Timestamp.fromDate(queryDate);


QuerySnapshot qShot = await _db
    .collection('content')
    .document(userID)
    .collection('favorites').
    .where('timestamp',isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:timestamp)
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .getDocuments().catchError((onError){print(onError);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try add a where sentence in your query. Like this:

```
QuerySnapshot qShot = await _db
    .collection('content')
    .document(userID)
    .collection('favorites')
    .where('timestamp',isGreaterThan:'5DAYSOLD_TIMESTAMP')
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .getDocuments().catchError((onError){print(onError);});
```

Comment: for more information about querys you can see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&t=880s

Comment: Maybe the new query fails because you have a "where" and "orderby" sentences, but when it fails see the logs, in there you can see a firebase link that will create the compose index that firestore need to perform the query. And then you can try again.

Comment: Thank you. Very easy to use. Just tried and it didn't fail. I don't have any data older than a day yet, so I'll test soon with one day old.

Comment: Yeah ... Rushed a bit. It does fail. Where can I find the error logs you mentioned?

Comment: Seems that I can't create indexes for two `timestamps`

Comment: I don't see an error, nothing loads, maybe I'm not handling errors right. I just went to my Firebase account and tried adding an index. But it doesn't allow me to to add two indexes for the same value. I just checked and the return is empty.

Comment: An alternative can be remove the orderBy sentence in the query

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do this

```
//Datetime
DateTime daysAgo= date.subtract(const Duration(days: 30));

//Apply to your firestore query
.where("date", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: daysAgo)
.orderBy('date', descending: true)
```